# Mule 3.5 Community throwing No Suitable Driver found

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I was working on the AnyPoint Studio with Mule 3.5 Community Runtime, while trying to connec to my oracle db it is throwing the following error at runtime

INFO  2014-05-30 12:16:32,875 [[externaladdresssearch].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'connector.VM.mule.default.dispatcher.1832211181'. Object is: VMMessageDispatcher
INFO  2014-05-30 12:16:32,875 [[externaladdresssearch].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'connector.VM.mule.default.dispatcher.1832211181'. Object is: VMMessageDispatcher
ERROR 2014-05-30 12:16:32,882 [[externaladdresssearch].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy:

---

Message               : java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.211.55.8:1521:mosaic (org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.connection.ConnectionCreationException). Message payload is of type: InterfacesRequestDto
Type                  : org.mule.api.MessagingException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
Payload               : uk.co.corelogic.mosaic.interfaces.common.dto.InterfacesRequestDto@6ac1abcf
JavaDoc               : http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html

---

I have used Generic DB connection The following is the DB config

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="jdbcDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" name="jdbcDataSource">
        <spring:property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.211.55.8:1521:mosaic"/>
        <spring:property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <spring:property name="username" value="fw"/>
        <spring:property name="password" value="fw"/>
    </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>
<db:generic-config name="Mosaic_Database_Configuration" dataSource-ref="jdbcDataSource" doc:name="Generic Database Configuration"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the `ojdbc.jar` included in your Classpath. There is a good tutorial provided [here](http://oraclesoaandoim.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/mule-esb-344-configure-oracle-jdbc.html) that details how to do this.

Alternatively, if you already have the jar in your classpath, I'd suggest trying a different spring bean. I've used the following to connect to an Oracle database previously:

```
<spring:bean id="dataSource" class="org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardDataSource" destroy-method="shutdown">
    <spring:property name="driverName" value="${Driver}"/>
    <spring:property name="url" value="${URL}"/>
    <spring:property name="user" value="${User}"/>
    <spring:property name="password" value="${Password}"/>
</spring:bean>
```

Comment: I have already tried the enhydra datasource and it is working, I forgot to update the dame, but still I am wondering why the standard spring datasource is throwing the exception?

Comment: I would be interested to know the same as I cannot see why it isn't. If you do find out, please update the question, it would be useful to know :)

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue. Place database driver, in the following path.,

```
AnypointStudio/plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.3.5.***/mule/lib/mule
```

If you are running from standalone, place the driver jar inside,

```
mule-standalone-3.5.0/lib/mule
```

But I am not sure why it is expected database driver when driver is packaged with the deployed app.