# How to set up suitable driver for jdbc on the Mule ESB Server?

Tags: jdbc, mule, mule-studio, sqlexception

Good day.
I created an Mule application in Anypoint Studio, in it I made a request to the Oracle and MsSQL databases.
When I run the application on the local machine is working properly, no problem.
Now I am trying to deploy application on stand alone server in the folder C:\ mule-standalone-3.4.0\ app. Application was deployed successfully. 
After that I tried to make a request to the web service and got the error:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc: sqlserver:
>   // ....

There are sqljdbc4-4.0.jar and ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar in the application folder ...\lib: 
I just read this post here [Mule 3.5 Community throwing No Suitable Driver found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948742/mule-3-5-community-throwing-no-suitable-driver-found)
I added into the config file next strings:

```
<spring: beans>
     <spring: bean id = "jdbcDataSource" class = "org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardDataSource" name = "jdbcDataSource">
         <spring: property name = "url" value = "jdbc: sqlserver: // MYSERV: 1433; databaseName = MYDB" />
         <spring: property name = "driverClassName" value = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
         <spring: property name = "username" value = "user_login" />
         <spring: property name = "password" value = "PASS" />
     </ spring: bean>
<spring: bean id = "jdbcDataSource" class = "org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardDataSource" name = "jdbcDataSource">
         <spring: property name = "url" value = "jdbc: oracle: thin: @ // MYSERVER.is.loc: 1521 / ORACLEINST" />
         <spring: property name = "driverClassName" value = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
         <spring: property name = "username" value = "user_login" />
         <spring: property name = "password" value = "PASS" />
     </ spring: bean>
</ spring: beans>
```

After that the application failed to deploy on a server with the following error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:
>   Configuration problem: Bean name 'jdbcDataSource' is already used in
>   this  element

Please help deploy the application with the possibility to access the database.
What I need to add into config or there is another way to allow to app communicate with DBs?

Comment: The problem was solved by adding ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar и sqljdbc4-4.0.jar into C:\mule-standalone-3.4.0\lib\mule

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency to your pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Of course i have these dependency in pom.xml:  `<dependency>
          <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
     <dependency>
           <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
           <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
           <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
 
    <!-- ORACLE database driver -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
   <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
   <version>11.2.0</version>
  </dependency>`

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you have created two beans: one for mssql and the other one for oracle database. But you have named the two spring beans 'jdbcDataSource' which confuse spring. I suggest to change their names and references for suitable names such as 'msqlDataSource' and 'oracleDataSource'.